# What can cause an "SCD is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow" error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, ssdt, slowly-changing-dimension

I created an SSIS package which includes several SCD data flows.  This works fine in Visual Studio SSDT, but when scheduled (using SQL Agent), it fails, with this error repeated for each SCD:

```
Code: 0xC0048020
Source: XYZ (SSIS.Pipeline)
Description: The version of SCD is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  End Error
```

The first thing that comes to mind is that, when scheduled, the package runs under a different user account.  However, I'd expect that to cause permissions problems.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013; the database is SQL Server 2014.  Neither has changed during the time I've been developing the package, there's been no upgrading, which seems to be what the error message implies.  I am developing the package on a server with SQL 2012 running, so that's used when testing within VS; from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197898/ssis-error-during-job-execution), that can have an impact for ADO.NET connections, but I'm using OLE DB.

Apparently SCD may not work with databases other than MS SQL, but I'm not using any such.  I've tried 32-bit and 64-bit mode, with no difference.

For this project, I'm violating two of my cardinal rules for SSIS: develop on the machine where the package will run, and don't use the built-in SCD tool.  I suspect that changing either one would fix this problem.

Comment: Step 1 is knowing SCD is a finicky, poor performing component... Assuming default installation path, what happens when you run the package from the command line and an ispac on disk? `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /package MyPackage.dtsx /project MyProject.ispac`